How to create a window of size 2048x2732 on my small monitor?
I have a Windows application that programmatically sets its main windows size to 2048x2732 when it starts, but since the resolution of my monitor is 1920x1080, the window size is reduced by the system.
Is there any system option that affects the maximum window size or allows large windows?
I need the window size to be exactly 2048x2732 to record some video (with Win+Alt+R).
EDIT1:
Looks like Nvidia DSR is not accessible on my laptop with RTX 3060:


There should be a picture like this:

EDIT2:
But I was able to do this with GTX 1060 on a desktop machine.

The short answer to your question is: You can't.
You can't make the windows have more pixels than the screen it's being displayed on, it's physically impossible.

The longer answer would be that with the right hardware (specifically Nvidia GPU supporting this) and the right software (Nvidia DSR) for the resolution magic, and a more fallible screen recorder - instead of the Windows built-in Game Bar recorder - like OBS.
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55007711/5518385

-1 because you start with you can't, then you explain that you actually can, but only list the NVidia solution, while AMD also has this, and AMD and NVidia graphics cards are used by the majority, so there is a high probability that OP can actually do this. The you can't therefor is very confusing.

The reason I wrote that he can't is since the question is about doing it with Win+Alt+R (Game Bar screen recorder), and also due to the fact that most people - without specifying - don't have discreet GPUs at all. You are very welcome to disagree

Depending on your GPU you have to use different methods to increase your desktop resolution beyond 1920x1080 (the output of your GPU) and have this output then be scaled down by your Monitor.
For example if it is NVidia, use the NVidia Control Panel > 3D settings > DSR - Factors and set a factor of 4.00x so that you can get a 4K output.
On AMD use virtual super resolution to increase the output to 4K.
Intel is trickier, you have to use third party software like the Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) from the monitortests.com forum to generate a custom profile (with an EDID override).
Whatever method you use, you should then be able to select a higher resolution in Windows Settings > System > Display.
The higher output resolution essentially means that your GPU does more work and your Monitor has to discard that detail anyway to squish the image again so this is normally very pointless.
But in your specific use case this should allow your 1920x1080 Monitor to display content as if it was a 4K Monitor.

This should be the accepted answer.

The answer of Overminded explains how to do it with hardware, which requires an NVidia GPU or AMD GPU that supports virtual resolutions to scale down the end resolution to fit your monitor.
In case you don't actually have the hardware, there is another way to do it using only software, or a second pc to replace a bit of the software.
If you use Oracle VirtualBox and create a Virtual Machine, then install windows on it, you can run it windowless. VirtualBox allows you to enable a Remote Desktop server, or you can setup the VM to be in your network and setup Remote Desktop access from inside the VM (the oracle one is easier though).
To enable the Remote Desktop server, with the VM turned off, go into the settings, Display, Remote Display, and at the top check Enable Server.
If you already have RDP setup for your own pc, change the port to something else.
Now you can RDP to localhost:3389 or whatever the port is that you set it to.
Now, if you create an .RDP file to connect to your Virtual Machine, and you change/add the following lines to the .rdp file using notepad:
I carefully assume your display is not in portrait mode, but landscape. If not, then flip the values for Width and Height.
desktopwidth:i:2738
desktopheight:i:2048
smart sizing:i:1

The smart sizing option will ensure that while your window is maximized, the resolution never changes and always scales the window.
You can also use a 2nd pc and run the software on there, enable Remote Desktop, and use the same RDP trick. This second pc can also be a terminal server, etc.
You can make the virtual window as large as you want, but the larger you make it, the less easy it will be to read. If you indeed have a portrait window, I will recommend to keep the 2738 for the height, but set the width to 4868 so you keep the aspect ratio of your display the same and it doesn't look all stretched.
